# Variation of height above ellipsoid when traversing an ENU vector

Tags: coordinate-system, geodetic

Given a point A on the ellipsoid, for which we have local ENU vectors (noting that the U vector is normal to the surface but does not point to the Earth's center). We move a distance 10km along the N vector (which is tangential to the Earth's surface). Due to the Earth's curvature, we end up 7.85m above a spherical Earth (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391470/find-distance-between-point-on-tangent-line-and-circle). All fine so far.

However, the radius of the Earth is not constant. When heading North (in the N hemisphere), the radius decreases. If A is at 40deg latitude, then the radius at our destination point is ~30m less than the radius at A. Why then do we not end up 37.85m above the ellipsoid? What correction should be applied to account for this effect?

I'm running this numerically by traversing the N vector in ECEF coords (i.e. in a straight line regardless of the shape of the Earth) and then converting back to long/lat/alt.

Comment: I think you're talking about the distance to the polar axis at a particular latitude OR you're using an ellipsoid rather than a sphere as the earth model. If using a sphere, the U vector does intersect with the center of the sphere.